# What is the importance and clear differences/similarities between convergence, stability and monotonous convergence in finite differences method??

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I know that stability and convergence are 2 faces of the same coin. however when it comes to convergence, I can't find why it is important for it to be monotonous. Maximum always decrease and minimum always increase. Is it because it will sensitive to perturbations? or will the stability of the solution depend on the initial conditions. If so, why does instability happen if the criterion of stability (Fourier's number) is satisfied?

I'm a bit confused, since this something i'm dealing with, and I can't understand it intuitively.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add more context. Convergence is a property of sequences in metric spaces. Monotonous convergence or the maxima/minima subsequence require an order on the space. There is no immediate connection to stability. Stability can be related to mechanical constructs or to dynamical systems and their equilibria/fixed points. Only the last topic so far has use for initial conditions. Quantitative claims on stability are based on linerizations, which requires a certain regularity/smoothness for the dynamical system.

Comment: i'm sorry. it's just a general question relating to the finite differences method. When I say stability, I mean the convergence of the numerical solution to the exact solution/insensitive to perturbations...

Comment: So you have some kind of convection-diffusion-reaction equation and discretize via method-of-lines and then apply low-order integration methods in time direction, seeing that as always explicit Euler tends to be unstable, implicit Euler is stable but more expensive and the trapezoidal method has smaller method error and is kind-of stable? What are the convergence statements in this context?

Comment: @LutzLehmann so in this context, the explicit Euler is only conditionally stable, so using this scheme, the solution only converges to the exact solution for a certain condition. But for the implicit Euler scheme, the solution always converges no matter what condition we have on the time step. Is that correct?

Comment: There's also something I don't understand. If we use the theta scheme for a pure diffusion PDE equation, we obtain that Fourier's number cannot be bigger than a certain expression in function of theta. When I use theta = 0, the fourier number should then be less than 0.5 for the scheme to be stable. but in practice, when I use Fourier equal to 0.53, the solution still converges. I don't understand why the difference between the mathematical model, and its exact application.

Comment: Yes to Euler, note that impEuler still is first order. To the second comment, not all upper bounds are sharp, and close to the limit most frequency components will be stable and the few unstable ones might grow slowly from floating-point noise to visible effects.

Comment: Please take your comments and use them to make your question better. As it is it is a closure candidate because it is too broad in topics and not clear enough in what exactly you are asking.